# Sum of an unknown sequence (perhaps arithmetic or geometric)

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

The problem is stated as thus:

> Given a sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$,
>
> $$ a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n = 1 + 2^{n+1} $$ for all $n$. Find $a_5$.

This is all the information that is given.

Comment: You don't need any more information, since you can recover $a_n$ by subtracting partial sums

Answer (score 3):

Using your relation for $n=4$ and $n=5$:
$$\begin{align}
a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4= 1+2^{4+1} &= 33\\
a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5= 1+2^{5+1} &= 65
\end{align}$$
So you get
$$
a_5 = (a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5)-(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4) = 65-33 = 32
$$

Comment: Note that the relation you have actually defines entirely the sequence, so you can recover all the terms (similar as what is done in [K. Jiang's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1809188/75808). Since is not necessary, though: you only need to apply the formula twice, as illustrated above, to recover any particular term of the sequence. (For instance, what is $a_{82943719}$?)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done quite easily. Let us first find $a_{1}.$ By the definition of the sequence, we have $a_{1} = 1 + 2^{2} = 5.$ We can again use the definition to see that $5 + a_{2} = 1 + 2^{3} = 9,$ so $a_{2} = 4.$ Continue as follows:
$$5 + 4 + a_{3} = 2^{4} + 1 = 17$$
$$a_{3} = 8$$
$$5 + 4 + 8 + a_{4} = 2^{5} + 1 = 33$$
$$a_{4} = 16$$
$$5 + 4 + 8 + 16 + a_{5} = 2^{6} + 1 = 65,$$
so we have
$$a_{5} = \boxed{32}.$$